# How to fetch an Array in Laravel using MongoDB database

Tags: arrays, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1005f8f2468f0fe0007c46"),
    "question" : "my question",
    "answere" : " my answere",
    "options" : [
            {
                    "A" : "dfd"
            },
            {
                    "B" : "fdf"
            },
            {
                    "C" : "fdfdf"
            }
    ],
    "explanation" : "my Explanation",
    "correctans" : "A",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-31T14:26:00Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-31T14:26:00Z")
 }
```

And now I want to print the options how can this possible. I am trying this.

```
@foreach($questions as $key => $question)
<tr>                         
 <td>{{$question->question}}</td>  
 <td>{{$question->answere}}</td>
 <td>{{$question->explanation}}</td>
 <td>{{$question->correctans}}</td>
 <td>
    @foreach($question->options as $key => $option )
       {{ $option->A }}
    @endforeach
  </td>
  <td>{{$question->updated_at}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

getting this error

```
"Trying to get property 'A' of non-object
```

Fetching the data  using this

```
$questions = Question::all();
```

Please tell how to fetch

Comment: What's the result of `{{ dd($option) }}`?

Comment: array:1 [▼
  "A" => "A"
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working this way only

```
 @foreach($question->options as $key=>$option )
     @foreach($option as $key=>$val )
         {{$key}} {{$val}}
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```